# Removing lines in a file that contain a certain word in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, sorting

My input file looks like this

```
car
dog
Rock
```

My output file that im trying to edit looks like this. my whole aim here to to remove all of the lines that contain the word car

```
cat car
sky rat
car cloud
```

Here's my initial code, the problem here is it only removes the line only when it  literally only the word which is "car" in this case

```
from __future__ import print_function
import linecache
import fileinput

must_delete = linecache.getline('Test.txt', 1)

for line in fileinput.input('output.txt', inplace=True):
    if line != must_delete:
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Is it okay to remove lines that contain `'scary'` since `'car'` is in `'scary'`?  What about `'Car'`?  Should `'Car'` and `'car'` be considered equal or does case matter?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I was going to say: use  `if must_delete in line:`  .. but you got a point

Comment: 'scary' is no where in the file or in my question

Comment: We don't know what's in your file.  Is `'card'` in your file?  How about `'carrot'`?  We can go all day on this.  The point is to find out if you want to do whole word matching.  You're currently doing whole-line matching which needs to be refined, but exactly how to refine it is the question.

Comment: Steven is providing an edge test case to properly define intended behavior.

Comment: I dont want to match the entire line i just want to check if the line contains that  particular word @StevenRumbalski

Comment: @StevenRumbalski yes im doing whole word matching, not line matching

Comment: Define contains!  Does `'card rat'` contain `'car'`?  If you do `'car' in 'card rat'` Python will say `True` because partial word matches are okay.  Does `'Car cloud'` contain `'car'`? If you do `'car' in 'Car cloud'` Python will say `False` because uppercase and lowercase do not match.  Is that what you want?  I have no idea because you haven't specified.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I want it to ignore capitalization for now and do an exact match to the word

Comment: @StevenRumbalski yes it is what i want

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re
import linecache
import fileinput

must_delete = "car" # linecache.getline('Test.txt', 1)

text = '''
cat car g
sky rat
car cloud
scary thing
''' 

with open("cleaned_file.txt","w") as clean:
    for line in text.splitlines() :          # fileinput.input('output.txt', inplace=True):
        if  re.search(r"(\b"+must_delete+r"\b)", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
            print ("deleting line:"+ line)
        else:
            print ("this line has to be kept in the output: " + line)
            clean.write(line+"\n")

# cleaned_file.txt has all the needed lines
```

Output:

```
this line has to be kept in the output: 
deleting line:cat car g
this line has to be kept in the output: sky rat
deleting line:car cloud
this line has to be kept in the output: scary thing
```

I use a regex consisting of the word you want to remove and two word-boundaries so the car must be a full word. `re.search()` returns `None` if the regex is not found.

As pointed out in the comments "scary" also contains "car" - thats the reason a simple `if "car" in "scary":` is not enough to weed out words that contain "car" but are not "a" car.

Comment: I'm trying to open a file and delete the words that contain the word 'car'

Comment: You are contratdicting yourself. Above you told us you want "to remove all of the **lines** that contain the word car"

Comment: Okay, make `must_delete` lowercase before the loop and do `if must_delete in line.lower().split():`